# FileObserver not catching events

Tags: android

I am trying to detect changes in Wifi settings, device is rooted.
This simple FileObserver does not catch events,
Any idea why?
Thanks 
Charles

```
public class WifiObserverActivity extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

FileObserver fileObserver;
private static Context context;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context = this;
    fileObserver = new FileObserver("/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf")
    {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path)
        {
            Log.i("FOBS", "Event on file " + path);
        }
    };
    fileObserver.startWatching();
    Log.i("FOBS", "startWatching " + "/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf");
    }
```

Comment: The file /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf exists on the device, but if I try to touch it with a program I get a FileNotFound exception. How can I connect to a file on the filesystem of the device?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file's directory wpa_supplicant.conf. Or if that doesn't work, use the wifi api in the android sdk. Check it every so often with a timertask or a service and see if that doesn't work.